# Сделать number_format для decimal

Tags: php

Дело в том, что я вывожу число 10000000000000000000000000000000 из базы, после обработки функцией number_format оно превращается в 9.999.999.999.999.999.635.896.294.965.248.
Вопрос: как сделать чтоб число стало 10.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000?

Comment: *вывожу число 10000000000000000000000000000000 из базы* Укажите СУБД, включая версию, и тип данных поля. *после обработки функцией number_format* Где именно? с какими параметрами?

Comment: @Akina без СУБД и параметров можно https://ideone.com/o64Xqt

Comment: @teran Ну а в таком случае остаётся только два вопроса. Первый - "А что ты ждал от float с его 14 (если повезёт - 15) цифирями?" Второй - "A нахрена тут `number_format`?"

Comment: @Akina СУБД - MySQL

Comment: У MySQL нет проблем в работе с такими числами - для DECIMAL 32 цифры не предел. В том числе и с их выводом. У PHP же при использовании встроенных типов данных - есть, да ещё какие!  Без GMP, BCMath или аналогичных - вобще нерешаемые.